# How to use app script to allow users to notify me which column they put their emails in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use the app script to code a function for google spreadsheets to allow me to be notified of which column is being used by users using the `.getResponseText()'.

> 

```
 function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
.createMenu('email')
.addItem('Validate email', 'Email finder')
.addToUi();
}
```

```
    //** Prompting user to specify email is in which column **\\
    function PromptBox() {

    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");

      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
      var prompt = ui.prompt("Email" , "Enter Email Column here" , ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL)
      var response = prompt.getResponseText();
      var button = prompt.getSelectedButton();

      {
    ui.alert("Email is " + response);


    }
     else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL)
      {
        ui.alert ("Email has been cancelled" + response);
      }

    }
```

Comment: Welcome. Google has a detailed example of the use of `prompt` and `getResponseText` [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response). have you tried to adapt that? Please edit your question to show any code that you have written so far.

Comment: hi! i updated it so u can see it now

Answer (score 0):

**The function prompting the user to specify email needs to have the same name as the one called in [createMenu().addItem()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus).**

Sample:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
   .createMenu('email')
   .addItem('Validate email', 'Emailfinder')
   .addToUi();
}

//** Prompting user to specify email is in which column **\\
function Emailfinder() {
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
    var prompt = ui.prompt("Email" , "Enter Email Column here" , ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    var response = prompt.getResponseText();
    var button = prompt.getSelectedButton();
    if (button == ui.Button.OK){
       ui.alert("Email is " + response);
    } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL){
        ui.alert ("Email has been cancelled" + response);
    } 
}
```